# WPMVC : Given multiple records, only one recordset is saved in database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two tables: productfilters and productfiltervalues.

In the first table I have records like, Books, Electronics, Apparels etc.

In the second table, there are records relevant to the records in first table i.e., when we edit Books, we can add values dynamically which are referred by the 'id' of 'Books', like 'Fiction', 'History', 'Poetry' etc. Likewise, we have different data for 'Electronics' and 'Apparels' too.

Now, when i edit both tables at a time and save them on one click, the first table records are saved as i wish but the second table records are truncated and the last set of records are saved in database.

For this functionality, I have overwritten the admin controller method 'create_or_save()' and it makes trouble. I have given the code below.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
if ($this->model->create($this->params['data'])) {
    $id = $this->model->insert_id;
    $this->load_model('ProductFilterValue');
        if(isset($this->params['data'][$this->model->name]['productfiltervalues']) && !empty($this->params['data'][$this->model->name]['productfiltervalues'])){
            foreach($this->params['data'][$this->model->name]['productfiltervalues'] as $productfiltervalue){
                $productfiltervalue['group_id'] = $id;
                $this->ProductFilterValue->save($productfiltervalue);
                }
            }
```

I have added two screenshots to understand this. 1. Add 2. Edit

[image: Records are added here]

[image: Edit to see the database]

only the last record is added. How to solve this? any wild guess? Thanks..

Comment: Maybe some code could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here:

```
$this->ProductFilterValue->save($productfiltervalue);
```

so while loop you are just replacing the value (i think),
it must be something like:

```
$this->ProductFilterValue->add($productfiltervalue);
```

I am not WP expert, and have no WP installed right now, but just to help you figure this out.
Hope that could help you

Comment: Thanks for the response Kim, but 'add' will also call the create_or_save() method only. I am almost found it. Will soon get back with the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: could you do `var_dump($this->params['data'][$this->model->name]['productfiltervalues'])` before foreach?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I have given the below code in the common partial layout of add/edit forms.

```
var clone ='';

        if(jQuery('.filter-input-html:first').length > 0)
        {
            clone = jQuery('.filter-input-html:first').clone();     
        }
        else
        {
            clone = html;
        }

        jQuery("#filter-value").append(clone);
        filter_value_row++;
```

and this caused the error.

I just removed the total if condition and replaced it with

```
clone = html;
```

and now it works fine. Thanks.